# Invalid floating point operation using SQRT()

Tags: sql-server

I receive an invalid floating point operation error when I `SQRT(X)` a value.

Under which reasons does this error occur, and what could I to to the `X` value to prevent this error?

For some context, the `X` value is a calculated average sales for stock items.

I have tried `SQRT(ABS(x))` with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: what is the data type for `x` ?

Comment: and on what values do you get the error?

Comment: The data type for X is numeric(20,8) from the source field.

Comment: The exact calculation is SQRT(2*50*ABS(X)) / NULLIF(B*0.2/12,0)) and B is a numeric(28,8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only case when SQRT(X) gives the error "An invalid floating point operation occurred" is when X is negative. However, you already fixed this by using the ABS function like this: SQRT(ABS(X)).

So, my guess is that the error does not really come from the SQRT function but from something else nearby. Let's look at the expression you gave:

```
SQRT(2*50*ABS(X)) / NULLIF(B*0.2/12,0))
```

This expression obviously has an extra right parenthesis. This makes me think that it is only a part of a larger expression, and that the larger expression is the reason for the error.

For instance, if B is 0 then the NULLIF() becomes NULL. You divide by NULL, thus getting a NULL result. Now, what do you do with this result? Maybe some more calculations that does not handle the NULL well?

There is a lot of guessing here. If my guesses did not point you in the right direction, then it would be helpful to know which values of B and X that give the error, and also the full statement that includes the expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is a T_SQL command that calculates the type of the variables. You can view the type of variable before calculating its square root.
The command is :

```
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY
```

(See the site https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/12/15/sql-server-how-to-identify-datatypes-and-properties-of-variable/)

On the other hand, I'm sorry to tell you that I do not know if it works with the 2018 version, because I do not have the means to check it. But you can find the equivalent command for your SQL Server version.
Hope that can help.